# How to get the attribute value which js setted?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a JSP page with a < table > and one of the rows is defined like this:

```
  <td list-action class="actionColumn d-flex justify-content-end">
    ID: ${appId}
  </td>
```

From javascript I am setting an attribute to this row:

```
  row.find('[list-action]').attr("appId", template.id);
```

When I am looking with inspecting mode I can see that the appId is set on <td, but the values are not shown.

[image]

Do you know how to show that value?

Answer (score 0):

```
 row.find('[list-action]').setAttribute("appId", template.id); ?
```

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute](https://mdn)

Comment: If i am doing what you said I receive the following error: TypeError: row.find('[list-action]').setAttribute is not a function. (In 'row.find('[list-action]').setAttribute("appId", alertTemplate.id)', 'row.find('[list-action]').setAttribute' is undefined).

Comment: But the attribute is already set in my case, but i don't know how to use it to display it